# How do i map an array of strings in a material ui select menuItem?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am trying to map an array of strings in a Select item in material UI over the menuItem. How do I do that?

```
const Form2 = () => {
  const courses = ["Educational Courses","Vocational Courses"]

  return (
      <>
        <form>
          <InputLabel>Courses</InputLabel>
          <select>
          {courses.map((course) => {
              <MenuItem></MenuItem>
           })}
          </select>
        <form/>
     </>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{courses.map((course, index) => {
    return (
       <MenuItem key={index}>{course}</MenuItem>
      )
 })}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in some cases, using `return` is not possible than, this can be the solution:

```
   {courses.map((value, key) => (
      <MenuItem
          key={key}
           value={value}>
           {value}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
```